# root running emacs

Tags: root, emacs, cpu-load

Today, after about 20 minutes of logging in my Ubuntu 10.4, I notice the CPU and hard disk usage going up. top revealed that root was running emacs23.

It is basically the same behavior described at [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1098516)

but there is no answer there. Any clue about this?

Comment: Was this perhaps after some kind of update?

Comment: No update today (or the last few days).

Comment: Is emacs your default editor? (which means another process my kick it off). What is the parent process? (type "$ ps -ef | grep emacs" and look at the second number, then look at which process has that as the first number).

Comment: emacs is not my default editor. I already kill the process. If it happens again, I will check the parent process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a cron job that executes emacs weekly for updating AUCTeX auto-loads.

You can expect that behaviour if you installed [auctex](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/auctex). To confirm, check out if the file `/etc/cron.weekly/auctex` is pressent.

Comment: Exactly! /etc/cron.weekly/auctex is present.

Comment: +1 to reward content addressable obscure knowledge.